# Convert a dataframe to a set of equalities for use as arguments of a function

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function in R that takes the name of a univariate density function as data, as well as the values of any parameters of the function, and find its maximum over a certain range of values.

If I know what the function is I can write as follows, for example for the normal density:

```
{
  optimize(f = dnorm, 
           interval = c(-2,2), 
           mu = mu,
           sd = sd, 
           maximum = TRUE)$maximum
}
```

But with an arbitrary function there is a problem.  I can find the names of the parameters using `formals`I have trouble giving that information to `optimize`.

I want to write something like the following:

```
modefind_general <- function(dist, parvalues, xmin, xmax) {
    dfun <- eval(as.name(paste0("d", dist)))
    
    parnames <- (dfun %>% 
                   formals %>% 
                   names)[-1]
    optimize(f = fun, 
             interval = c(xmin, xmax), 
             [???],
             maximum = TRUE)$maximum
}
```

My question is what goes into the [???] box? It needs to be:

```
parnames[1] = parvalue[1],
parnames[2] = parvalue[2],
```

and so on to the end of `parnames`.
I can create a dataframe with the two columns `parnames` and `parvalue` but I don't know how to convert that to a set of equalities.

Responding to the discussion I show below a complete example of what I want to do given a specific function and values for the parameters in which I am interested. I wish to convert that code into a function that takes as data a distribution and a set of values for its parameters.

```
library(sn)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) 
pdf = function(x, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
  dst(x, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
cdf = function(x, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
  pst(x, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
qf = function(p, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
  (qst(p, xi, omega, alpha, nu))

modefind = function(xi, omega, alpha, nu){
  optimize(f = pdf, 
           interval = c(-10,10), 
           xi,
           omega,
           alpha,
           nu,
           maximum = TRUE)$maximum
}


plotskewt = function(xi, omega, alpha, nu, xmin = -1, xmax = 1){
  assertive::assert_all_are_greater_than(xmax, xmin)
  t1 = qf(1/3, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
  t2 = qf(2/3, xi, omega, alpha, nu)
  w = modefind( xi, omega, alpha, nu)
  
  df = data.frame(x = seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = 500)) %>% 
    mutate(y = pdf(x, xi, omega, alpha, nu),
           z = cdf(x, xi, omega, alpha, nu) 
           )
  
  plot = ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(w,w), y = c(0, 1)), 
              aes(x, y), 
              colour = "green") +
    geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(t1,t1), y = c(0, 1)), 
              aes(x, y), 
              colour = "blue") +
    geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(t2,t2), y = c(0, 1)), 
              aes(x, y), 
              colour = "blue") + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(1/3, 2/3), 
               colour = "blue", 
               linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x, y = z), colour = 2) +
     
    scale_y_continuous(
      limits = c(-0.2, 1),
      breaks = round(c(0, 1/3, 2/3, 1), digits =2))   
  return(list(plot = plot, df = df))
}

xi = 0
omega = 1
alpha = -7
nu = Inf


result = plotskewt(xi, omega, alpha, nu, xmin = -3) 
result$plot
```

Comment: Your use of `eval` falls under the “don’t” category. It’s simpler and cleaner to use `get(paste0("d", dist))` — but even that is questionable, and should almost certainly be replaced with a proper parameter. In other words, just pass e.g. `dnorm` instead of `"norm"`. What you’re currently doing is an anti-pattern known as [stringly typed code](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have noticed it seems to be a bit of a convention to use variants of the `get(paste0("d", dist))` idiom in packages dealing with distributions - this is how `fitdistrplus` uses its arguments, though it takes the extra step of testing for existence of an object of mode 'function' with that name before `get`ting it. This is better again, but still not as good as insisting on a user-supplied function object (I might not want my distribution function to start with a 'd'). I suspect it's a result of the naming convention of the distribution functions in `package:stats`

Comment: @AllanCameron Ah, I didn’t know that. Unfortunately specific instances of bad practice are quite widespread through the R package ecosystem. Outside of r-lib and tidyverse I would caution against blanket imitation of practices found in R packages: most are not developed by competent programmers. (Many *are*, but it’s not obvious which ones.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph sure, a package being useful doesn't mean it's written well. I find the idiom confusing, unnecessary and a little suspect myself.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't understand why using `eval` is bad, nor why `get` is better but still not good. In my intended application I process the density, the distribution function and the quantile function of each distribution in the data. It would be inconvenient, and a potential source of error, to have to provide all three functions, eg `dnorm`, `pnorm` and `qnorm` as data.

Comment: @JeremyC Two related guidelines are at play here: (1) use a descriptive function (`get()` tells you exactly what happens here; `eval()` does not). (2) Use the least powerful function to do the  job. `eval` is an extremely powerful (and potentially dangerous) function. Using it here is breaking a butterfly on a wheel. — But, furthermore: *`eval()` does something different!* `get()` will work for [non-syntactic names](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic), but `eval()` will fail. This happens to not matter in your case, but it matters in general.

Comment: @JeremyC The second part of your comment is interesting, and makes this use more justified. I would still be (strongly!) tempted to solve this differently, i.e. by providing strongly-typed objects wrapping these functions, e.g. an object `norm` which is defined as `list(density = dnorm, distribution = pnorm, quantile = qnorm)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Many thanks for the explanation. I find that @Onyambu's suggestion of `match.fun` works. Is that an acceptable usage? The `list(density = dnorm, distribution = pnorm, quantile = qnorm)` method works but surely is error prone if one is working, as I am, with a large number of distributions: so easy for a `pnorm` to remain when `dnorm` is changed to `dlnorm` etc.

Comment: It seems you are abit confused as to what you want. The mode of a distribution is inddepenent on the data. given the parameters of the distribution, you do not need to know the data to find the mode. EG given the mean and variance of normal distribution you can always find the mode. So your `modefind` function should not have any `xi` but should be written as given in the solution.

Comment: @JeremyC Oh, I would totally generate these objects using an automatic helper to avoid the redundancy in code (because I agree: having this redundancy is error-prone). But I would do that inside the implementation, far away from the public user interface, and thus avoid having stringly typed objects in the user interface. But at this point I have to admit: this is an ideological decision without strong technical advantages.

Comment: @JeremyC And regarding the other comment: yes, `match.fun()` is even better than `get()` here, because it continues working (as it should!) even when the user defines a local non-function object with the name `dnorm`. This may seem odd, but it’s the established behaviour of R (for instance, the following works, and is *expected* to work: `c = 1; c(c, 2)` yields the vector `c(1, 2)`).

Comment: @Onyambu In my example `xi` is one of the parameters of the distribution. I agree with you that data play no part in determining the mode. My `modefind` function is needed because without knowing what probability distribution is defined by `dist` I don't know how to find the mode algebraically.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your helpful comment on use of automatic helper. In my case the only user of the code will be myself, so I do not need to worry about the public user interface. Thanks also for your endorsement of @Onyambu's `match.fun` idea. I'll adopt that.

Comment: Still the idea presented below soles the problem. Why do you think it does not? You werae asked for an example where tje idea wont work, yet you gave a ditribution where the idea works..

Comment: @Onyambu My difficulty is that I have names of parameters and the values that they take but I do not know how to give that information to `optimiz` automatically. I can do it by typing out `xi =3` etc but I want the code to do that automatically. The crucial thing is that the process must be automatic. I can get it to work but not automatically.

Comment: Use `do.call` function, ie `do.call(optimize, c(your_function, as.list(your_args), interval=.., maximize=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an argument called `parvalues`, you can pass the extra arguments into `optimize` directly using dots (`...`)

```r
modefind_general <- function(dist, ..., xmin = -1, xmax = 1)  {
  
  optimize(f = get(paste0("d", dist)), ...,
           interval = c(xmin, xmax),
           maximum = TRUE, tol = .Machine$double.eps)$maximum |>
    round(15)
}
```

Which results in

```r
modefind_general('norm', mean = 0, sd = 1)
#> [1] 0

modefind_general('norm', mean = 5, sd = 3, xmin = 0, xmax = 100)
#> [1] 5

modefind_general('chisq', df = 3, xmin = 0, xmax = 100)
#> [1] 1
```

As Konrad points out in the comments, it would be better to pass a distribution function directly as the first argument:

```r
modefind_general <- function(dist, ..., xmin = -1, xmax = 1)  {
  
  optimize(f = dist, ...,
           interval = c(xmin, xmax),
           maximum = TRUE, tol = .Machine$double.eps)$maximum |>
    round(15)
}
```

So you could call your function like this:

```r
modefind_general(dnorm, mean = 0, sd = 1)
#> [1] 0

modefind_general(dnorm, mean = 5, sd = 3, xmin = 0, xmax = 100)
#> [1] 5

modefind_general(dchisq, df = 4, xmin = 0, xmax = 100)
#> [1] 2
```

Comment: You should use `get(..., mode = 'function')` or `match.fun`. It is safer to use `match.fun` instead. Note that you can also use `match.fun` to be able to have the oportunity of passing the dist as either a string or a function

Comment: Although I understand your answer, it does not actually answer my question. What I have are the names of the parameters and the values I wish to give them but what I need is an automatic method for turning that information into the series of equalities that would replace the '...' in `optimize`.  Code such as `do.call(qnorm, as.list(c(1/3, par)))`, for instance, calculates the lower tertile of the normal distribution with parameters defined by `par` but I cannot see how to do something like that in `optimize`.

Comment: Sorry. My previous comment was addressed to @AllenCameron.

Comment: @JeremyC can you post an actual example of the data that you would be starting with and an example of how you would use the function? The `...` is the best way to copy arguments directly into `optimize` (I think arguments are what you mean by equalities here, such as the `sd = 1` in `dnorm(5, mean = 1, sd = 1)`. If you have the parameters stored as say, data frame columns, then you can't use `...` directly, but it's only a small tweak to the function to get it to work. However, the exact format of what you want to input into the function matters here.

Comment: @AllanCameron I have edited my original question to include an example of the processing I wish to do.